# Reindex catalog categories url issue

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, url-rewrite, reindex

My problem is that all of the categories url are not working. There are in some kind of infinite loop so I tried  to reindex from admin panel. The result are the same: infinite loop. After that I tried from console. I used this command:
php indexer.php --reindex catalog url

and the result is this:
Product Attributes index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded                              ; try restarting transaction' in /home/shopdev2/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
    Stack trace:
    #0 /home/shopdev2/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
    #1 /home/shopdev2/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_exec                              ute(Array)
    #2 /home/shopdev2/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql-                              >_execute(Array)
    ..................

Do you have other idea how do i reindex my urls ? thx
**[UPDATE] after executing the command php -indexer.php -reindexall**
this is the result:

```
Product Attributes index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction' in /home/shopdev2/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /home/shopdev2/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home/shopdev2/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/shopdev2/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /home/shopdev2/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /home/shopdev2/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('DELETE FROM `ca...', Array)
#5 /home/shopdev2/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('DELETE FROM `ca...', Array)
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to /var/locks & delete all the index_process_*.lock files, then try to re-index again

Comment: tryi to reindex all or just the catalog-url ?

Comment: whichever you want

Comment: I tried as you said. Please check my update

Comment: Check /var/locks, if files created again, then delete all, and re-index one by one, because you've faced timeout

Comment: I still get the timeout , what should I do ?

Comment: Are you getting the timeout for every indexing or, only for a particular indexing?

Comment: for any indexing

Answer (score 1):

If possible, I would restart mysql. Then try to run the indexes via the command line again.
Sometimes MySQL gets stuck and this has been my only resolution for those issues.
Sometimes the mysql.log can offer some hints on whats going on.
Also, Magento may still be doing a re-index so its just stuck until it completes.
Restarting Mysql is drastic but it may get it working again.
I would check to see if you have low or no traffic on the server before doing that. You will interrupt the customers that are on the site.

Answer (score 1):

Contact your hosting provided and ask to increase the lock wait time out.
Also try to debug why your indexation is taking time and is not throwing any error while re-indexation.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem in my project. Dont worry. In this case, i did url rewrite management modification in my admin panel.

1. Login to phpmyadmin -> select database -> Run following sql command.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
TRUNCATE TABLE core_url_rewrite;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

2. Now you can go to admin panel. Catalog -> manage products as well as manage categories.

Change the url's of categories and products.

I hope it will help to you.